# PHP delete everything after comma (including comma)

Tags: php, strip

I just can't get my head around the syntax for this. I have an array `$foo` and I call it within a function: `wp_list_pages($foo);` (this is a wordpress site).

I found this code online but can't get it to work...
I've tried both of these ways and it doesn't seem to do anything. Can anyone help?

```
 <?php $mystring = $foo;
list ($before,$after) = split (',', $mystring);
echo $before; 
?>
<?php wp_list_pages( $foo ); ?>
```

or this:

```
<?php $has_comma = (stristr($foo, ",")>-1) ? 1 : 0;
if ($has_comma) {
list ($before,$after) = split (',', $foo);
$foo = $before;
} ?>

<?php wp_list_pages( $foo ); ?>
```

Comment: Why you don't use regex to just replace everething after comma with empty?

Comment: Is there only one comma in the string or is it like *keep everything before the first comma*?

Comment: keep everything before the first comma

Answer (score 4):

```
if (false !== ($pos = strpos($foo, ','))) {
    $foo = substr($foo, 0, $pos);
}
```

or if you're sure that there is always coma, it can be simplier:

```
$foo = substr($foo, 0, strpos($foo, ','));
```

Comment: so then this overwrites the original $foo, and I can echo out the new version?

Answer (score 0):

assuming $foo has some string in it for example "This is a short, boring sentence", then:

```
list($before,$after) = split(',',$mystring)
//$before => "This is a short" 
//$after => "boring sentence"
echo $before; //prints "This is a short"
```

If you are not seeing this behavior you need to make sure $foo has some string in it.

Answer (score 0):

That example is a bit too convoluted.  Here's a simpler one:

```
<?php 
$mystring = "a,b,c,d egg";
$n = strpos($mystring, ',');
echo substr($mystring, 0, $n)
?>
```

This one just finds the index of the first "," in $mystring and gets the string up until that point.

If you want an array-based example, here is one that uses explode, since split is deprecated:

```
<?php 
$mystring = "a,b,c,d egg";
$array = explode(',', $mystring);
echo $array[0];
?>
```

So explode splits $mystring on "," so that each item separated by a "," becomes its own element.  Naturally the first item is the 0th index, so that's how you truncate after the commas.

Answer (score 0):

`split()` is deprecated, try use `preg_split()`, or `str_split()`, see in php manual: http://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.split.php